# eliminate render-blocking resources jquery on mobile device

Tags: jquery, pagespeed

i have 2 websites [miniartikel.com](https://www.miniartikel.com/) and [spacexzone.com](https://spacexzone.com/) on one of those websites i get error "**eliminate render-blocking resources**" on miniartikel.com website.

[pagespeed insights](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmqHv.jpg)

I've equated the speed settings on the two websites with the default plugins from the theme and litespeed. However, for some reason one of these websites raised an error message "**eliminate render-blocking resources**" on a **mobile device** on the miniartikel.com website.

I've tried various ways this week and the results can't get rid of the problem on [pagespeed.web.dev](https://pagespeed.web.dev/).

I've also tried looking for "**network**" in the chrome devtool but I can't seem to figure out what's going wrong around there.

can anyone here help me why am i getting the error even though the settings are the same ?

Comment: sorry, fix with preload font. thanks